# AWS SQS - Append data to message on retries

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a SQS queue which is accessed by a lambda. I'm leveraging the retry capability provided by SQS using redrive policy and forwarding the message to a dead letter queue on max retries. I would like to append additional data to the message on each retry , but would like SQS to continue managing the retries. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.

The [ReceiveMessages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html) action provides an attribute called `ApproximateReceiveCount`, which is a counter that automatically increments with each receive... but otherwise, it isn't possible to change anything about a message in the queue.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. I would like to use retry capability provided by SQS. Is there a different alternative available to have additional messages associated with a message id or should I resort to using my own retry mechanism / storing in an external datastore?

Comment: Depending on the task, I usually pop a message from the queue, store it in a database, then process it and delete it from the queue.  If I already have the message-id in the database, I know I've already seen the message, so I know at that point that I'm in a situation where the message has already been seen.

Comment: Hi,  is this still not possible? Because I was looking if I can change a user define messages attribute